# Access to exposed service in Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, kubernetes-service

For the setup details:

- Kubernetes Cluster (1 Master with ip .222 - 2 Nodes) in a VMWare environment
- Installed Ingress Controller, sample app from [NGINXINC REPO](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/complete-example)

Problem & Question:

- Unable to access the application from outside the Kubernetes Cluster
- What do i miss ?

Configuration:

```
kubectl get svc
```

output

```
 NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
coffee-svc   ClusterIP   10.109.97.144   <none>        80/TCP    60m
```

A Curl from inside the Master ( with ip .222)

```
curl http://10.109.97.144/coffee
```

output

```
Server address: 10.36.0.5:80
Server name: coffee-bbd45c6-82w6t
Date: 08/May/2019:09:09:29 +0000
URI: /coffee
Request ID: a9602071f75126323a48efeb3552bb55
```

the ingress

```
kubectl get ingress

NAME           HOSTS                   ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
cafe-ingress   test.me.at                        80, 443   62m
```

- **Goal: Access the service from a different machine from the browser:**

ps: I also tried a curl with

```
curl http://test.me.at/coffee
```

output

```
Failed connect to test.me.at:80; Connection refused
```

Add1: kubectl -n nginx-ingress get svc

> `NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)
>   default-http-backend   ClusterIP   10.111.28.170    <none>       80/TCP 
>   nginx-ingress          NodePort    10.101.248.204   <none> 80:31080/TCP, 443:31443/TCP`

Comment: can you paste output of "kubectl -n nginx-ingress get svc" ?

Comment: Ensure that the service fronting your ingress controller is exposed outside the cluster on the ports you expect to access your services from.

Comment: @VasilyAngapov  this is the output

NAME                          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S) 
default-http-backend   ClusterIP   10.111.28.170    <none>                80/TCP                       
nginx-ingress              NodePort   10.101.248.204  <none> 80:31080/TCP,443:31443/TCP

Answer (score 0):

you should use NodePort to expose the service.
If you use ClusterIp you can not curl from other machine